# Powershell - Net Use credentials not working

Tags: powershell, variables, net-use

i want to automate net use through powershell to bind a lot of share drives.

first i fetch the credentials via `Get-Credentials`, then i want to use the credentials later.

```
$cred = Get-Credentials -Message "Enter credentials"
net use K: \\192.168.100.50\E$ /user:$cred.username $cred.password
```

This throws the error `Network password wrong` (translated from german)

When i enter it like that:
`net use K: \\192.168.100.50\E$ /user:Admin Adminpassword`

It works? When i replace `$cred.password` with the plaintext password and only use the username variable it still says `Network password wrong`

What is conflicting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use powershell to do this, because `Get-Credentials` store your data as securestring, `net use` can't work with it.

```
 $cred = Get-Credentials -Message "Enter credentials"
 New-PSDrive -Name K -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "ComputerName\FilePath" -Persist -Credential $cred
```

Comment: oh, thanks! i read somewhere that new-psdrive doesnt add drives in explorer but only works for within powershell, thats great

Comment: @FlyingThunder it adds drives in explorer with parameter `-Persist`